# Spring MVC No mapping found for http request

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mapping

Error:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/gefp/home.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'gefp'
```

I don't know what went wrong it was working fine but all of the sudden it started giving this error. Please help me with it..
thanks in advance.

Controller

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/home.html")
    public String index(ModelMap model)
    {
        model.put("username", "user");
        return "home";
    }
 }
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="gefp" version="3.0">
  <display-name>GEFP</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>

    <servlet-name>gefp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-name>gefp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>jpaFilter</filter-name>  
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>  
    </filter>  

    <filter-mapping>  
        <filter-name>jpaFilter</filter-name>  
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Application Context

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/gefp" />
    <property name="username" value="gefp" />
    <property name="password" value="abcd" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="1" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="gefp" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<context:annotation-config />

<tx:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="gefp.model" />
```

gefp-servlet.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
```

Comment: Are you missing <mvc:annotation-driven /> in your gefp-servlet.xml? If so that might be the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I sort it out, actually every thing was there but accidentally the build automatic option was not checked so the controller class wasn't getting complied when ever the project was run.